# Magento CE 1.9 Add Product to Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, cart, rest-api

I am making rest api's for add product to cart for that I wrote this code:

```
public function _create(array $data) {

        $id = $data['id'];
        $qty = $data['qty'];

       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')                 
                         // load the product object
                         ->load($data['id']);

       $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
       $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

       $quote->collectTotals()->save();

 return json_encode(array("customer", $quote->getId()));

}
```

from this the product successfully adding in shopping cart(sales_flat_quote table) and it returns quote ID but I want to add this product to particular(logged in) user's cart for that I load quote from customer like this:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(21);

// Load quote by Customer
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
             ->loadByCustomer($customer);
```

But still it is not associating with customer(in table customer ID is 0). Please let me know where I am doing wrong or I have to do more for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your complete code is like this

```
public function _create(array $data) {

        $id = $data['id'];
        $qty = $data['qty'];

       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')                 
                         // load the product object
                         ->load($data['id']);

       $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(21);

       // Load quote by Customer
       $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
              ->loadByCustomer($customer);

       $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
       $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

       $quote->collectTotals()->save();

      return json_encode(array("customer", $quote->getId()));

}
```

Instead of, load quote by customer object try to load this quote by customerId like this

```
// Load quote by Customer
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
         ->loadByCustomer($customer->getId());
```

I've tested this one on Magento 1.9.0.1 just right now and it works fine.
Here my code

*I can access the user because it is identified by my application via token ...*

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($this->getApiUser()->getUserId());
$customer_ID = $customer->getId();

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_ID);
```

Hope it's help you

**The working code is:**

```
$store = $this->_getStore();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store->getId());

    $customer_ID = 10;

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_ID);

    // load quote by customer
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_ID);

    $quote->assignCustomer($customer);

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         // set the current store ID
                         ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                         // load the product object
                         ->load($data['id']);

    // Add Product to Quote
    $quote->addProduct($product,$data['qty']);

    // Calculate the new Cart total and Save Quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Regards

Comment: No flow still it is adding product as a guest and I am not using oauth so I do not have token.

Comment: And if you use this method :

`$customer_ID = 21;
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_ID);`

then call your addProduct method like before

`$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();`


To be sure you can also Assign the quote to your customer's model:
`$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
where $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_ID);`

Comment: do you have an error when you call this one ?
try to log $quote please and give the log

Comment: flow u made my day $quote->assignCustomer($customer); is the trickkkk....I am updating your answer :)))))

Comment: happy to help you. I spend a lot of hours / days to do that ;-)

Comment: I can not upvote as my reputation is low :(  I saw lot of questions but did not find this answer, do not understand why..

Comment: My reputation is too low also.... 
I've got alot of rest module in stock, so if you have questions tell me ;)

Comment: flow now customer details are adding into sales_flat_quote table but product is not showing on frontend. To showing details on frontend do I have to save quote on different table like(checkout/cart) ??

Comment: Hi

no, the "checkout/cart" is only when you procede to checkout (one page for example)
The "cart" in the website is equal to "quote" model during the navigation. To be sure, products added in the cart / quote are enabled in the magento's admin ?

Comment: Flow I did it from other method, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Flow have you faced this problem? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68664/products-in-cart-magento-ce-1-9

Comment: Nope because my user is authenticated by oAuth... So only users authenticated by oAuth can access to the cart model.
Before to add an item in the customer's cart, you might be check if customer is currently connected or not.

Comment: I Stuck in a problem how to return multidimensional array you can check full problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726549/return-collection-or-multidimensional-array-or-array-inside-array-in-php/30728585#30728585.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
// load quote by customer and store...
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStore($storeId)->loadByCustomer($customerId);
$quote->addProduct($product, 1);
$quote->setIsActive(1);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code to logged in user's cart

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
umask(0);

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$product_id = '98';
$qty = '1'; 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Product added successfully');

$cart =array(
'status' => True,
'Message' => 'Product added to cart successfully.'
);
echo json_encode($cart);
```