# Change quote_id(Cart) after logout in Magento CE 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cart, rest-api

**Brief Introduction:** I am trying to make custom rest api's for magento. To add a product in customer's cart, I followed following steps:

1) Log In customer(code):

```
public function loginUser( $email, $password){
         require_once ("app/Mage.php");
         umask(0);
         ob_start();
         session_start();
         Mage::app('default');
         Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));

      //   $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
         $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
         $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
         $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(1);
         $customer->setStore($store);
         try {
             $customer->loadByEmail($email);
             $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
             $session->login($email, $password);
          }catch(Exception $e){

          }
    }
```

2) To add product to customer's cart(code):

```
Mage::init('default');
$id = '1'; 
$qty = '1';
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

3) Logout Customer:

```
Mage::getSingleton("customer/session")->logout();
```

**Problem:** After Login I added a product into cart, it successfully added in corresponding customer's cart after that I logged out and then added a product to cart as a guest but the product was added in same(previous) **QUOTE_ID** and then again logged in from different account(not previous customer) and again I added a product and it again added in same **QUOTE_ID**. 
The Resultant carts of both user's are like this:

```
customer1: 3 products
customer2: 3 products
```

But they should be like this:

```
customer1: 1 product
customer2: 2 product
```

To Remove quote id, in logout I add reserveOrderId to null(generally it is used after checkout) but no solution:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setReservedOrderId(null);
```

**For more Information:**

- `customer_id = 1 and quote_id = 5` returns after 1st add(Got customer ID from session)
- `customer_id = null and quote_id = 5`  returns after 2nd add(after
  logout)
- `customer_id = 2 and quote_id = 5` returs after 3rd add(logged in
  from different account)

Answer (score 2):

To reset the quote either of the following should work.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuoteId(null);
```

QuoteId is checked if not empty when called on. If empty (null) a new one is generated which would return a new quote.

Comment: Sander I almost got the solution using   `cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote(); `  with help of this I am able to get previous quote_id but it creates problem when I fetch cart products, the products price and subtotal is showing null.